# How to move negative numbers in Thumb

Tags: assembly, arm, thumb

I'm trying to move a negative value in thumb.

In ARM its easy,

`mvn r0, #1`

How can I move negative values to registers in Thumb?

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose load the positive value and negate, or load from memory (literal pool) as usual with `ldr`.

Comment: If you are on ARMv6T2 or ARMv7, then in exactly the same way `mvn r0, #1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In ARM its easy

Actually, it is not so easy.  For instance, if you want to emulate `return -1;` you need the following,

```
mvn r0, #0
```

The reason is that `mvn` is **not** (or bits flipped) and **negative** with twos complement needs you to **not** with subtraction of one.  More information is found on the [ARM site](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0068b/BABJAJIB.html).

We can see examples at god bolt,

1. [ARM](https://goo.gl/RN4Lxl)
2. [Thumb](https://goo.gl/M8Dsr5)
3. [Thumb2](https://goo.gl/GvqfCb)

The **thumb1** version is,

```
mov r0, #1
neg r0, r0
```

The `neg` or **negate** is doing the twos-complement arithmetic for us.  Newer versions of the **thumb** instruction set (often called **thumb2**) have the ability to do a version of the `mvn` instruction.  You can simply write `mov r0, #-1` and let the compiler/assembler figure out the arithmetic for you.  It will examine the constant and select the `mvn` encoding with the source being a little more *humon* friendly.

Obviously, if you only have **thumb1** and no `mvn` instruction exists, the `mov r0, #-1` will not assemble and you need some two (16 bit) instructions/opcodes to achieve the same thing. There are probably a variety of ways to get a negated value using two instructions (depending on constant value and/or surrounding code).

---

If you really intended `mvn r0, #1`, I would suggest a comment of `; -2 to 'r0'`.

If you intended a bit mask, then `ldr r0, =0xfffffffe` can be used and it will pick `mvn r0,#1` if it is available.  However, your question title said **negative** which usually implies twos-complement.

Answer (score 0):

there is a T1 encoding of MVN.

```
mov r0,#1
mvn r0,r0
```

or mvns if your assembler is true to the language (which gnu of course isnt).

This is all spelled out clearly in the many architectural reference manuals